# Windows 7 x64 double installed on separate partitions

Tags: windows-7, windows, hard-drive, boot, partitioning

Recently, through a series of unfortunate and mysterious events, the Windows 8 partition of my Dell Inspiron 1440 came down with a case of knock-off Cryptolocker, and eventually I had to reformat. Seeing as how I had no recovery media for W8, and it was angering me anyway because the drivers for my firmware aren't updated that far anyway (which caused a myriad of problems installing simple things like Minecraft, despite compatibility mode), I eventually caved and reformatted the partition.

Now, due to the stupidity of drivers not reaching that far (the laptop isn't *that* old, it was only made to come with Vista), there was a point in time where I partitioned off a segment of the HDD and installed my old W7 Ult x64 onto it. Which worked great, I had a dual boot of 8 x64 and 7 x64. Upon booting from a shutdown, I was given the option to choose which partition to boot into by name of the OS.

After wiping my W8 partition entirely (to clear all infected data. We're talking data nuke here, there is nothing left whatsoever), I successfully installed W7 Ult x64 onto that section too. At the very least I can separate the work partition from the play partition and that way I won't be dragging on my ram with silly business applications and media while trying to play skyrim and other such games, right?

...right?

Apparently not. Despite both sections of the HDD being independently installed and bootable (at some point in time), and the contents of the W drive having NOT changed, the computer no longer gives me any options to change which partition I boot into, and boots into the primary every time.

What can I do to log back into the other partition of my hard drive on the W7 x64? I'd really rather not have to spend my time transferring, dissecting, and re-arranging program data and caches to merge the two partitions into one hybrid drive if I can avoid it.

---

The repair tool in the answer offered does not work. I have repaired all options, system, C, and D (previously the "W" drive), and I still cannot access the other installation to boot.

However, as I was exploring options in the booting process to attempt to see the other partition I began to spam f10 on boot.

The screen that appeared had the directory of the Windows boot on it (`\Windows\system32\system\winload.exe`) followed by "Partition: 1" and then a command line with something written in it in the way of no options. Does anyone know if this screen will allow me to force the BIOS to access the second partition for booting?

I've Googled this option as well, but turned up nothing productive. I just want to access my second partition. @_@

Comment: “that answer doesn’t work” should be a comment. The rest of your edit should have been an edit all along; don’t apologize for it. Now, click on “flag”, “moderator attention”, explain your situation, and ask to have your two IDs merged.

Comment: Sadly moderators can no longer merge accounts but I have submitted a merge request on your behalf and hopefully you should be contacted soon regarding this. If you do not hear soon then please use the [contact form](https://superuser.com/contact) and select "Other" to query the status of the merge.  Just for future reference if you need to merge accounts you should use the [contact form](https://superuser.com/contact) and select "I want to merge accounts".

Comment: Thank you very much for initiating the merge request, it worked beautifully. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows 7/8 boot files are always on THE active partition on a MBR disk.

The choice to boot to different Windows installations on separate partitions comes from boot loader entries stored in BCD (Boot Configuration Data) which again is on THE active partition.

If you want to have a boot choice for two different Windows 7 installations on two separate partitions you need just two separate loader entries in the common "System" BCD.

There are several ways of adding a second boot loader entry in BCD.

The simplest way is to use bcdboot.exe utility - one command line like this:

**bcdboot N:\Windows**

where N is the drive where your second Windows resides.

N is just an example drive letter - check your drive letter, it is maybe D: or E: .....

The suggested tool in my previous answer does just that - it finds the correct drive letter and executes the outlined command.

Comment: For whatever reason, the tool did not perform that command properly at any point in time.

Once I opened an elevated console and entered it manually, it dual boots fine. Thanks so much for posting the command, and thanks for suggesting the tool. I have no clue why it didn't perform the way it was supposed to, despite the tool claiming the commands were executed properly.

This having been said, my problem is solved and you have my utmost gratitude!

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Visual BCD Editor](http://www.boyans.net).

The tool has an option (on F9 key) to scan for installed Windows versions on different partitions and add a boot entry for any OS which is not present in BCD (Boot Configuration Data).

Even better it is to start with "[Dual-boot Repair](http://www.boyans.net/dual-boot-repair-tool-for-windows-8.1-update.html)" tool. It writes on "Automatic Repair" the proper boot files for a dual/triple boot system. Then using Visual BCD Editor you can simply add another boot entry for other Windows installations (if not already present in BCD).